# await Task vs Task.GetAwaiter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Why does the following example not work (both texts change at the same time):

```
Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                textnew1.Text = "Dispatched";
            });
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                textnew2.Text = "BackgroundTask";
            });
        });
```

And this one does (the first text changes, and the second one follows after two seconds):

```
Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Task.Delay(2000).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                textnew1.Text = "Dispatched";
            });
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Task.Delay(2000).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                textnew2.Text = "BackgroundTask";
            });
        });
```

Why isn't the `Task.Delay` awaited in the first code? What is the difference between `await Task.Delay` and `Task.Delay().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `async void`, your first code example is equivalent to

```
Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(FirstTask));
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(SecondTask));
        });

private async void FirstTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    textnew1.Text = "Dispatched";
}
private async void SecondTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    textnew2.Text = "BackgroundTask";
}
```

Because the signature of DispatchedHandler is `public delegate void DispatchedHandler()` you can't return a task with it. When you perform a `async void` then `RunAsync` thinks that the task is complete as soon as the `await Task.Delay()` is hit.

Answer (score 1):

As [Scott's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50361156/1159478) correctly explains, the reason your asynchronous version is moving on even though you're awaiting the delays is because `Displatcher.RunAsync` accepts a `void` delegate.  As far as the appropriate solution, I'd strongly suggest avoid using all of the `async` lambdas in your code.  `Task.Run` does understand how to handle `Task` returning methods, but you're still making lots of things a lot harder on yourself by structuring your code as you have, in particular you're not leveraging the fact that `async` methods capture the synchronization context so that you don't have to be manually marshaling code to the UI thread in the first place.

You can rewrite the answer as:

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
textnew1.Text = "Dispatched";
await Task.Delay(2000);
textnew2.Text = "BackgroundTask";
```

If you have some long running non-UI CPU bound work to do, and a UI update to make when done, rather than putting the *while thing* in a `Task.Run` lambda with dispatcher calls throughout simply use `Task.Run` to specifically call the non-UI CPU bound work, and then do whatever needs to run in the UI context after awaiting it:

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
textnew1.Text = "Dispatched";
await Task.Run(() => SomeBackroundWork());
textnew2.Text = "BackgroundTask";
```